# Moodle and Postgres - frequent database connection error

Tags: php, postgresql, moodle

I've installed `Moodle` with `Postgres`. The db configuration looks like (yeah, I did it in a bit hackish way):

```
$CFG->dbtype    = 'pgsql';      // 'pgsql', 'mariadb', 'mysqli', 'mssql', 'sqlsrv' or 'oci'
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';     // 'native' only at the moment
$CFG->dbhost    = "my-moodle-db.net' connect_timeout=10 sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert='/path/to/cas/allCAs.pem";  // eg 'localhost' or 'db.isp.com' or IP
$CFG->dbname    = $pwd_name;     // database name, eg moodle
$CFG->dbuser    = 'moodle';   // your database username
$CFG->dbpass    = $pwd_pwd;   // your database password
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';       // prefix to use for all table names
$CFG->dboptions = array(
    'dbpersist' => true,       // should persistent database connections be
...
```

My installation works almost fine but once in roughly 10 requests I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Database connection failed

And the page is rendered immediately though I set connection timeout to 10 above.

Is there any other place to fix connection timeouts in PHP?

Can I make moodle somehow retry the connection before returning the error to me?

Comment: Many causes are possible: network issues, database contention, database does not accept more than X connections, moodle connection pool is full, ...

Comment: @Nic Is there any way to debug it in Moodle? I'm a newbie with the both moodle and PHP..

Comment: Hi, I am no moodle expert myself but I found this: https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/Performance

Comment: Can you connect to the DB and let us know 1. How many max connections are allowed, and 2. how how many connections are being used.. (you should run the query for 2 over and over and try to hit it the same time as you're seeing the connection error)